# RegExp how replace single quotes on double quotes in this example

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
let text = "'I'm the cook,' he said, 'it's my job.'";
// Change this call.

function replaceQuotes(string) {
  const actionReplace = string.replace(/(^')|('$)|('(?=.*)(?=\s))|(?: '(?=.*))/g, "#");

  return actionReplace
}

console.log(replaceQuotes(text));
//expected result → "I'm the cook," he said, "it's my job."
//actual result → "zI'm the cook,z he said,zit's my job.z"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last alternation you have a space that is not replaced.

Just add this space in the replacement part, for doing this, I've remove all your useless groups (that slow down the process) and create another one that contains the space to keep.

```js
let text = "'I'm the cook,' he said, 'it's my job.'";
// Change this call.

function replaceQuotes(string) {
  const actionReplace = string.replace(/^'|'$|'(?=\s)|( )'(?=.*)/g, '$1"');

  return actionReplace
}

console.log(replaceQuotes(text));
//expected result → "I'm the cook," he said, "it's my job."
//actual result → "zI'm the cook,z he said,zit's my job.z"
```

Comment: @CSG: The first group captures the space before the single quote, the last component of the alternative. [Here is a detailled explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hjwphh/1)

Answer (score 2):

for `"` charactes `\` is put in front of it.

So you can just change `"#"` to `"\""`

or u can change `"#"` to `'"'`

```js
let text = "'I'm the cook,' he said, 'it's my job.'";

function replaceQuotes (string){
 const actionReplace = string.replace(/(^')|('$)|('(?=.*)(?=\s))/g, "\"").replace(/(?: '(?=.*))/g, " \"");
 return actionReplace
}
console.log(replaceQuotes(text))
```

Comment: Space is lost after "he said," + space + "it's my job."